# Can we use docusign api from the html webresource in Dynamics CRM 2013 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

Is it possible that we can use the DocuSign API from the custom html webresource in Dynamics CRM 2013 Online to upload and send the documents to the DocuSign.

Actually I want to create a new interface from where I can select the documents and also send the documents to the DocuSign to get the embedded signing url.

Can you please guide me on the right direction?

--

Thanks and Regards

Sandeep

Comment: Do you have some basic code started?

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign API facilitates integration with any other system which allows integration -- so, this question isn't so much about using the DocuSign API.  i.e., the true question is really: in Dynamics CRM 2013, is it possible to (and if so, how do you) develop a custom page and call other (non-Dynamics) web services from that custom page?  As long as Dynamics allows you to do custom development such that you can call an API and use data from the API response(s) to update data in Dynamics, then you can integrate Dynamics with DocuSign by using the DocuSign API.